# Gluon Application opens very slow in Android platform

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I have been developing gluon applications using javafxports and Gluon .
here's link to my [project](https://github.com/guruprasaad123/WifiSchedular).
I have developed my own version of navigation drawer.
And the app works fine when launching it on desktop platform.
but when launching the app on Android platform it takes almost 40 seconds to open.
Am getting a blank screen before opening (ie. for 40 sec ).
Which is very long time for any user.
When the apps opens after some period of time , it runs smoothly with no issues.
please enlighten me where the App lacks.

Comment: When you have a look at the Android Monitor results for method profiling, you will see that most of the time is spent in `com.sun.javafx.image.impl.BaseByteToByteConverter.convert`. That seems to be caused by the use of an gif image. If you change the gif file, e.g. for a jpg, the start up time will be significantly reduced.

Comment: are u sure? Anyhow I'll try ur idea too! @jns

Comment: I don't get such a long time with a black screen, maybe 3 or 4 seconds. What is your device (and Android version)? On the other hand, the app is a mixture between JavaFXPorts/Gluon and third party frameworks... so probably a big refactoring could be done. I.e Transitions, Navigation Drawer, ... are already part of Gluon Mobile.

Comment: Redmi 3s prime running on android Marshmallow(version : **6.0.1**) @jose Pereda

Comment: As,you suggested .gif image was responsible for the delay ,when I removed the gif image from fxml file ,the app runs faster ,smoothly thanks @jns .But why does it spend so much time displaying a simple gif in android , whereas loads instantly in desktop.

Comment: thanks @JoséPereda the apps works fine now after removing a .gif